# Nginx try_files redirect not serving css/images

Tags: html, css, nginx, configuration

I'm trying to redirect all requests under https://example.com/user/whatever to my "Get Our App" page, at `https://example.com/get_app.html`

in my nginx.conf I have the following block setup:

```
#Redirect all requests under /user/ to the "get App" page
  location /user/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get_app.html;
  }
```

The html file gets served but the css and images are not shown. Just a plain white page with my html. The page is served correctly if I just type `example.com/user/whatever`. What am I doing wrong? Why isn't nginx serving the file correctly when coming from a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing my config as:

```
location /user/ {
   return 301 https://example.com/get_app.html;
}
```

since using try_files was trying to fetch css from `example.com/user/whatever/css/` and I do not know how to fix that. The redirect above should be enough for what I'm trying to achieve.